# angular 7 validation on edit page binding

Tags: angular, angular7

The Plot:

I have a page the displays user information, name, email, etc.. and a toggle switch that puts the page into edit mode but to simplify I'll just use last name.

```
<div *ngIf="isReadOnly">
  <dl>    
    <dt>Last Name:</dt>
    <dd>{{ user.lastName }}</dd> 
  </dl>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!isReadOnly">
  <form [formGroup]="aboutForm">
    <mat-form-field >
      <input matInput formControlName="lastName" placeholder="last name"  [(ngModel)]="user.lastName"/>
      <mat-error>Last Name is required</mat-error>
     </mat-form-field>
  </form>
</div>
```

so in my component.ts I have a formBuilder

```
this.aboutForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  lastName: ['', Validators.required ]
});
```

The antagonist:  for angular I do believe they are moving from the ngModel,

The climax..aka the question: if true how do I bind the data to the edit field lastName and how exactly should the  tag look like to throw the error "Last name required"  keeping in mind there are many other fields on the page as well.

Your answers will be a credit...thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.aboutForm.patchValue({})` and provide a partial of the form. Usually I create forms in constructor (due to strict mode) and patch the value in onInit

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to setValues you can do: `this.aboutForm.get('lastName').setValue('testName');`
if you are looking to getValues you can do: 
`this.aboutForm.get('lastName').value;`

For setting the error: 
`<mat-error *ngIf="lastName.invalid">Last Name Required</mat-error>`